# Different Crontab - Linux Debian

Tags: linux, debian, cron

What are the differences in using crontab editing directly:

```
vi /etc/contrab
```

And using:

```
crontab -e
```

Because if you use one or the other, the commands inside the file are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crontab command manage crontab files for USERS. These crontab are defined in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` directory ; they are not intended to be edited directly !

The `/etc/crontab` is the SYSTEM crontab file, which can be edited directly.